# Trying to install deepstream.io via npm

Tags: deepstream.io

I installed deepstreamhub via npm package, while using commands on node.js command prompt i got some error.
error:-no git binary found in $PATH.
I think i have properly installed npm package but i got this error while giving the commands(npm install deepstream.io).
I also searched for git folder but nowhere find that.

npm ERR: code ENOGIT
npm ERR: error while executing:
npm ERR: undefined ls-remoten -h -t ssh://git@github.com/uNetworking
npm ERR: No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR: Failed using git.
npm ERR: Please check if you have git installed and in your path.
npm ERR: A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR: C:\users\raki\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-04-18T06

Answer (score 0):

seems you don’t have git installed which some dependencies use. You can try using npm install —production deepstream.io and if that gives same error you can use the binary from https://github.com/deepstreamIO/deepstream.io/releases/tag/v3.2.4, install git or look at different install options for distributions on deepstream.io

Answer (score 0):

It's `npm install @deepstream/server` for the server.

And `npm install @deepstream/client` for the client.